# How Powershell handles newly generated file while it has already started running

Tags: windows, powershell

There are a bunch of log files in the folder, and I uses below PowerShell command to query the files which contains specific key words.

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-String "keyword" -List | Select Path
```

It may take 1 minute to get the result. During the minute, there are new log files generated inside this folder.

Will the newly generated files be included in the search scope of this command?

Comment: no they will not

Comment: In Windows PowerShell they might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the newly generated files be included in the search scope of this command?

They *might*, depending on the name with which they're created and whether you're using Windows PowerShell or a newer version.

In the Windows PowerShell version of the FileSystem provider, the underlying file system enumerator used by .NET to list files can return files created after the enumeration begun - we can observe this by creating a folder with a bunch of files, and then create a new file *while* listing the existing ones:

```
# create a temp folder
$tmpFolder = New-Item -Path $env:TMP -Name ([IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName()) -ItemType Directory

# create a bunch of files named file_a_*
1..100|ForEach-{
  New-Item -Path $tmpFolder.FullName -Name "file_a_${_}" |Out-Null
}

# now enumerate the files - attempt to create a new
# file after the first existing file has been returned
$folder |Get-ChildItem |ForEach-Object {
  if (-not (Test-Path (Join-Path $folder.FullName file_z))) {
    New-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Name file_z
  }

  # output enumerated file name
  $_.Name
}
```

You'll find that in Windows PowerShell, the last file name listed is `file_z` - even though `file_z` didn't even exist when `Get-ChildItem` began!

Comment: But how does it know the exact time to end the counting? For example, the system keeps writing new files into the folder, will powershell wait untill there is no new files coming for a period of time?